# How to dynamically create nested objects while reading a file in java?

Tags: java, object, nested

Let's say I have a text file which includes the line below.

```
Add apple banana strawberry
```

When I read the line and split it by spaces. I get `apple, banana, strawberry` and I want to create nested object with the classes I defined and with using decorator pattern

```
new apple(new banana(new strawberry()))
```

I tried this;

```
new splited[1](new splited[2](new splited[3]())))
```

but it did not work. How can I create this dynamically because each line can include different number of fruit. How can I do it without using if statements for each combinations like 2 nested or 3 nested?

Comment: use factory pattern to get the object.

Comment: Are `apple`, `banana`, and `strawberry` classes that you've already defined? If not, then you need to rethink your approach (you can't create a class from an arbitrary String). If yes, then use reflection: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html

Comment: "new apple(new banana( new strawberry()))  " does it make sense

Comment: Have you tried reflection? `Class.forName()`

Comment: To create a class from an arbitrary String, you need something like [JavaParser](https://javaparser.org/).

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat easy if all of your fruit implement a common interface. It's a lot more difficult if they don't, to the point where I'd probably suggest using another language altogether. Java's not suited for that.

If they implement a common interface, you can use [`Class.forName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) to get the class, and then [`getConstructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) to be able to instantiate the objects:

Basic interface (yours would probably declare more useful behaviour) :

```
public interface Fruit {
    String getName();
}
```

Apple:

```
public class Apple implements Fruit {
    private final Fruit child;

    public Apple(final Fruit child) { this.child = child; }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "I am an apple " + (child == null ? "" : child.getName());
    }
}
```

Banana can be basically identical to Apple, just with a different name.

Strawberry:

```
public class Strawberry implements Fruit {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "I am a strawberry";
    }
}
```

Main method is below. We need to iterate in reverse through the array in order to build the child objects first.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(final String... args) throws Exception
{
    String[] splitted = {"Apple", "Banana", "Strawberry"};
    Fruit prevFruit = null;
    for (int i = splitted.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        final String className = splitted[i];
        final Class<? extends Fruit> clazz = (Class<? extends Fruit>) Class.forName("my.pckage." + className);
        if (prevFruit == null) // if first, use no-arg constructor
        {
            prevFruit = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
        }
        else
        {
            prevFruit = clazz.getConstructor(Fruit.class).newInstance(prevFruit);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(prevFruit.getName());
}
```

Sample output:

> I am an apple I am a banana I am a strawberry